# Computational and decision Problems: definition and NP-completeness

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

My question is focused on two points:

1. Is the set of decision problems a proper subset of computational problems?
2. Is the class NP defined only on decision problems, hence, for (1), a proper subset of general computational problems?

These two points are relevant to define NP-complete and hard classes: if (2) holds, can I than conclude that computational problems that are not proper decision problems (e.g TSP or Shortest Path) cannot be in NP (simply because not defined) and hence, not NP-complete?

Lastly, if (2) holds, I would never need to show that a computational problem is in NP when demonstratig its NP-hardness, is not it?

Thank you in advance for the answer and sorry for any imprecision.

Comment: You might benefit from reading the [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard) on Computer Science Stack Exchange that covers this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The class NP only consists of decision problems by definition.  There is a related class FNP that generalizes NP to any sort of output instead of just yes or no answers.

Decision problems are a proper subset of computational problems.  Optimization problems like Traveling Salesman are easily converted to decision problems, however, so if you're being asked whether TSP is NP-complete then you're probably being asked about the decision problem variant of it.